# Error when trying to get the value of a MAX query in node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I need to get the last id from my database table, so I have to use `MAX` in order to achieve it, so this is the sql query I am using: `SELECT MAX(id) FROM payments`

The issue comes when I try to get the value from the object as it throws this error: `id is not defined`

server.js:

```
app.post('/sendMail', function(req, res) {
    getLastPaymentId().then((data) => {
        lastPaymentId = data.lastPaymentId;
        console.log(lastPaymentId.MAX(id)); //here I want to get the value 
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});

function getLastPaymentId() {
    const idPayment = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbConnection.getLastPaymentId().then(data => {
            resolve(data)
        })
    });
    return Promise.all([idPayment]).then(data => {
        return {
            lastPaymentId: data[0]
        }
    })
}
```

dbConnection.js:

```
function getLastPaymentId() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM payments";
        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
module.exports.getLastPaymentId = getLastPaymentId;
```

Result when just printing the object (`console.log(lastPaymentId)`):
[image]

It is `null` because I have no rows in my database yet.

Result when printing the value (`console.log(lastPaymentId.MAX(id))`):

[image]

It should print `null` instead.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I have just remembered that I had a similar issue in the past and the answer I got, has worked in this case as well: [How to access to the value when doing a COUNT() using node-mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144356/how-to-access-to-the-value-when-doing-a-count-using-node-mysql)

Sorry and thanks anyway!